# Web/Desktop Client for Azure Event Hub

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

Is there a Web/Desktop client to view messages being sent to Azure Event Hub, or do we have to use Event Processor Host at this point? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Afaik there is no ready made tool to view the content so yes, you will need to write code to do that.

There is one other option I can think of, using [Event Hubs Capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-capture-overview):

> Azure Event Hubs Capture enables you to automatically deliver the streaming data in Event Hubs to an Azure Blob storage or Azure Data Lake Store account of your choice, with the added flexibility of specifying a time or size interval. Setting up Capture is fast, there are no administrative costs to run it

The Azure Blob storage blobs or Azure Data Lake Store files with the content of the events can then be viewed using the [Azure Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/).

You will incur costs for the used storage though.